# Android activity destroyed but not garbage collected?

Tags: android, memory

I have a class named `Util` where I keep all my useful methods (download images, scaling rotating bitmaps, downloading music, playing music, etc...)

```
public class Util{
   public static Bitmap downloadImage(Context context, String url) throws SocketException {
      // Implementation
   }

   public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float degree) {
      // Implementation
   }

   // And other stuff
   public static int getApplicationVersion(Context context){
       // Impl...
   }
}
```

If I have two or more activities and I'm calling a useful method in each of the activity, is this will be a memory leak? Does the `Util` class will be like a "bridge", holding a reference between activities?

```
public Activity_A extends Activity{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
      Bitmap bitmap = Util.downloadImage(this, "http://static.asd....");
   }
}

public Activity_B extends Activity{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
      Bitmap bitmap = Util.downloadImage(this, "http://something");
      bitmap = Util.rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90f);
   }
}
```

Or calling in a fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
   @Override
   protected void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
      // inflating...


      Util.playBackgroundMusic(getActivity(), Constants.MUSIC_1);

      Log.i("APP", "Application version is: " + Util.getApplicationVersion(getActivity());
   }
}
```

Does this will cause memory leak? I am so confused...

Comment: In a word, yes.  Never hold static references to anything in an activity.  A Bitmap is bound to the context of the Activity.  Read this. http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

Comment: @Simon that's not true, Romain Guy was referring to Drawable holding a reference to its owning Activity, Bitmap does have such reference and can be quite safely cached.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a problem if you held a reference to an activity inside the static `Util` class, because it would prevent the activity from being garbage collected even after it's finished.

But in your case I don't see any memory leak issue.